# how to get history of an object in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use django 1.11 and I have a book model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user_borrowed = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def borrow_book(self, user):
        if self.user_borrowed is not None:
            return False
        self.user_borrowed = user
        self.save()

    def return_book(self):
        self.user_borrowed = None
        self.save()
```

it's like a library system. all I want to do is to know which users borrowed a special book. in fact **all users**. for example I want to get this result:

```
[
{ "username": "user_name_1", "date": "2018-02-08T14:13:22.142497"},
]
```

this means that user_name_1 borrowed this book at the above time.
so how to do this ?

thank you.

Comment: Well, your model doesn't store that information. You would need a separate "Borrow" model that records the user who borrowed the book and the time they did so.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't want to add this info to my model.

Comment: Then there is no way to get the output you want.

Comment: @DanielRoseman would you please write it ? I don't have the idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django-simple-history, then it will store history of that model, and you can get data u want. https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/